# Is there a free php search engine that doesn't use MySQL?

Tags: php, search-engine

I've found several paid options and several options with PHP/MySQL, but does anyone know a free option for implementing a site search option on my page that doesn't use a MySQL database?

Comment: google custom search http://www.google.com/sitesearch/

Comment: That's not self-hosted, and not based on PHP though. Why can't you use mySQL?

Comment: And it costs money.  Google search now charges and their lowest package is:  Up to 20,000 queries per year
One year is just $100
I was hoping to not use mysql because I have so many sites.. would be a pain to configure.  As a last resort, I may though.

Comment: @Andi For what it's worth though - I think setting up mySQL for each site might well be the least painful way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programme the search functionality yourself and you're using PHP, then you could try the Lucene component that's in Zend Framework.  It'll create a file-based index for you, so no MySQL, and you can use a variety of search syntax on it.  The index file should also be compatible with the Java implementation of Lucene.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.lucene.html

Comment: i appreciate the offer..  that's a bit over my head though.  :)  there's a nice alternative on code canyon (http://codecanyon.net/item/php-search-engine/89499) that I might just get.  Just thought I would check for a free solution first.